# unable to register new user (ERROR 500 - Internal Server Error!). Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, register

I am working on live site tuxedosonline. its in magento1. My problem is as a guest user i am able to click any link ,categories, or etc.  when i am trying to register new user or login with account and click on any link it display me
 Error 500 internal server error! 
 If you get this message repeatedly please contact the webmaster.
 I had checked all my previous updated file there is no new file in my server i don't know how to remove this . please guide me
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When facing a 500 error the first thing you should do is search for your web server error log.

From the logs, you can find the clue.

The 500 internal server error generally occurs due to:

- Wrong file permissions
- Low PHP memory limit
- Wrong server configuration (like illegal content in .htaccess file etc.)

Please verify the above points and come back if nothing helps.